# Encode password from php to nodejs crypto

Tags: php, node.js, cryptography

I have this encode in php and want to pass to node.js using crypto

```
$password = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($_POST['password'])));
```

I don't have much experience with that, and don't know how play with the pack()
Any idea?

Comment: This is a bad way to hash passwords. See this: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523

Comment: For a (much) better password derivation search for PBKDF2; this function is available on PHP and JavaScript/crypto library